# Does the directivity of a λ/2 dipole antenna depend on its length?

Tags: antenna, dipole, wavelength

They tell me to choose the correct answer (one and only one) regarding a half-wave antenna from the following options:

a) Its directivity depends on its length.

b) They all have the same radiation resistance.

c) The electric field and the magnetic field are proportional.

d) All of the above are correct.

The thing is that b) is correct because the resistance is approximately 73.1 Ω. c) is also correct since they are related as E/H =  η, where η is the impedance of free space. The one that generates the most problems for me is a) because, in principle, the directivity of a half-wave dipole is constant and equals 2.1 dB, which would make it false. However, I think that its length is limited by the wavelength of the emitted radiation and should be  l=λ/2, which would lead us to choose d).

Comment: I'd have to choose (d).

Comment: Without a definition of element diameter or height above ground, I would seriously doubt (b).

Answer (score 2):

You are right.

a) is false, because directivity is a relative measure that stays the same for all half-wavelength dipoles, b) is true, c) is inherently true, and because a) is false, d) is false.

Since this sounds like a ham radio exam question: if that is actually the case, maybe drop a quick email to your national ham association about it, they have the lobbying power to get it fixed. If this is a university exam question: quick email to the person responsible for that exam.

Regarding what you would do if asked in a real exam: take the path where you feel you make the last error. In this case, that feels like acting as if a) was true, thus checking d).

Answer (score 2):

**a** sounds a bit tricky. The length is already fixed, L = λ/2. All half-wave dipole antennas for a certain frequency (or wavelength) have the same length and the directivity is the same for all. But for dipole antennas **in general**, different lengths have different directivity. For example, a half-wave dipole has a directivity of 1.64 (or 2.15dB =10 log(1.64)) whilst a short dipole (L < λ/10) has slightly less, 1.5 (or 1.76 dB = 10 log(1.5)). So **a** is false.

For **b**, radiation resistance does depend on the length of a dipole antenna, **in general** i.e. proportional to the square of the length. But again, for specifically half-wave dipoles for a certain frequency (or a wavelength), it's all the same. So **b** is true.

**c** is already true.

These all make **d** false.